# Create secondary form before main form while keeping FormMain as main form?

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

In the Delphi 10.1 Berlin IDE, with a VCL Form application project, in the Project Options dialog, I have these settings:

[image]

Now I want the `formOptions` Form to be created BEFORE the `FormMain` Form while keeping the `FormMain` Form as the Main Form. The reason is: The main form could load data in its `FormCreate` procedure (where `formOptions` still has not been created), but to process these data it needs the settings from the `formOptions` form.

But as soon as I drag the `formOptions` item to the top of the list, also the main form combobox above changes to `formOptions`!

So how can I make the `formOptions` Form to be created BEFORE the `FormMain` Form while keeping the `FormMain` Form as the Main Form?

Comment: Remove it from the auto-list, and use formOptions := TformOptions.Create instead of Application.CreateForm.

Comment: You mean in the `DPR` project file?

Comment: This works. So I do have to use `nil` as `AOwner` because the main form has not yet been created: `formOptions := TformOptions.Create(nil);`. Is using `nil` as owner a correct procedure and do I have to destroy `formOptions` manually at program end?

Comment: Auto-created forms use `Application` as the Owner.  If you use a `nil` Owner instead, you must manually `Free` the Form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first `TForm` that is created with `Application.CreateForm()` becomes the VCL's `Application.MainForm`, and cannot be changed.  So do whatever initializations you need to do before `CreateForm()` assigns the `MainForm`.

You have two options:

1. Remove `formOptions` from the auto-create list (thus removing the generated `CreateForm()` call for it), and then create it manually yourself in code.  `CreateForm()` does not assign the `MainForm` until it is fully created, so you can actually handle this in one of two different ways:

   a. directly in the project's `.dpr` file :

   ```
   Application.Initialize;
   Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
   formOptions := TFormOptions.Create(Application);
   Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
   Application.Run;
   ```

   b. in the MainForm's `OnCreate` event:

   ```
   procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     formOptions := TFormOptions.Create(Application); // or even Self
   end;
   ```
2. move your shared settings to a `TDataModule` (or even a standalone class) instead, and then (auto-)create that object before creating either of the Forms. `FormMain` and `formOptions` can then retrieve their settings from that object when needed:

   ```
   Application.Initialize;
   Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
   Application.CreateForm(TSettingsDM, SettingsDM);
   Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
   Application.CreateForm(TFormOptions, formOptions);
   Application.Run;
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations and the solutions!